# save email from outlook to local drive using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

i am trying to save a selected mail from outlook to a folder dynamically created with mail's subject name. The code ran successfully for one mail. if i select different mail and try to run the macro it is showing path not found error. My code is below:

```
Public Sub OpslaanMails()
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim fName, sName As String
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    fName = "F:\Test\inwards\"
    Set oMail = OlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    sName = oMail.Subject
    makeSelectionDir (sName)
    sPath = fName & "\" & sName & "\"
    oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName & ".msg", olMsg
        
        For Each oAttach In oMail.Attachments
            oAttach.SaveAsFile sPath & oAttach.FileName
            Set oAttach = Nothing
        Next
    
End Sub

Sub makeSelectionDir(sName As String)
Dim fName, sPath As String
fName = "F:\Test\inwards\"
sPath = fName & sName
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not .FolderExists(sName) Then .CreateFolder sPath     'error is in this line
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: See https://www.slipstick.com/developer/saving-messages-to-the-hard-drive-using-vba/ - note the `StripIllegalChar` function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sName does not contain any characters illegal in a file name, such as ":".

Answer (score 0):

I used your idea and changed two or three things to make it more robust.

Put this in a module in Outlook VBA Editor and run, having selected an email.

I also added the time and date at the beginning of the folder and email file names.
I left the part about saving file attachements but know that they are already embedded in the `.msg` file.

```
Const ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = Array("*", "/", "\", "?", """", "<", ">", ":", "|")

Sub SaveEmailToFile()
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sObj As String
    Dim oAttach As Attachment

    'Select email and process subject
    If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No emails are selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    With oMail
        sObj = oMail.Subject
        
        'Remove illegal characters from email subject
        If sObj = "" Then
            sObj = "No Object"
        Else
            For Each s In ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS
                sObj = Replace(sObj, s, "")
            Next s
        End If
        
        'Get date and time string from email received timestamp
        dateStr = Year(.ReceivedTime) & "_" & _
            Month(.ReceivedTime) & "_" & _
            Day(.ReceivedTime) & " " & _
            Hour(.ReceivedTime) & " " & _
            Minute(.ReceivedTime) & " " & _
            Second(.ReceivedTime) & " "
    End With
    sPath = "C:\Someplace\" & dateStr & sObj & "\"

    'Create folder
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(sPath) Then .CreateFolder sPath
    End With

    'Save email and attachements
    oMail.SaveAs sPath & oMail.Subject & ".msg", olMSG
    For Each oAttach In oMail.Attachments
        oAttach.SaveAsFile sPath & oAttach.FileName
    Next oAttach
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. i tried it but am still getting path not found error. However when i tried that in other system the code is working perfectly. I also enabled all macro's in Trust centre in my system and still getting error.

Comment: Are you sure the folder you're trying to save the emails in exists (the `sPath` in my code or the `fName` in yours). Could you also try and find out which line causes the error ? (F9 to place a breakpoint on the selected line, F8 to execute the next instruction when in break mode. When in break mode, hover a variable to preview its value or right click > Add Watch...)

Answer (score 0):

I could only recreate the error

> path not found

if `fName` was not valid.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public Sub OpslaanMails()

    Dim fName As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sPath As String
    
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim oAttach As Attachment
    
    fName = "F:\Test\inwards\"
    Debug.Print "fName: " & fName
    
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    sName = oMail.subject
    Debug.Print "sName: " & sName
    
    ' Double slash accepted by Windows but not by some programmers
    'If Right(fName, 1) = "\" Then
    '    fName = Left(fName, Len(fName) - 1)
    '    Debug.Print
    '    Debug.Print "fName: " & fName
    'End If
    
    ' Double slash after fName preferable to no slash
    sPath = fName & "\" & sName & "\"
    Debug.Print "sPath: " & sPath
    
    makeSelectionDir fName, sPath
    
    ' Possible illegal characters in sName not addressed.
    ' Do not test with replies nor forwards,
    '  the : in the subject is not a legal character.
    oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName & ".msg", olMsg
    
    For Each oAttach In oMail.Attachments
        oAttach.SaveAsFile sPath & oAttach.FileName
        Set oAttach = Nothing
    Next
    
End Sub


Sub makeSelectionDir(fName As String, sPath As String)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
        ' Test for fName
        ' Otherwise there is file not found error in the create
        If .FolderExists(fName) Then
            ' if subfolder does not exist create it
            If Not .FolderExists(sPath) Then
                .createFolder sPath
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "Folder " & fName & " does not exist."
            'MsgBox "Folder " & fName & " does not exist."
            End
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Inconsistency of `sName` vs `sPath` has been addressed in

```
If Not .FolderExists(sName) Then .CreateFolder sPath
```